# Why Use Temporary Tables In Large Result Sets Whats The Gain

Tags: sql-server

Why use temporary tables in stored procedures that are returning large result sets. How does this help performance? Is there an example out there of maybe a join of several tables returning a large set of data and how a temporary table may help performance of this query in a stored procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience they may be helpful in limited situations when a query is so complex that the query optimizer is struggling to come up with a decent plan. Breaking such a query apart and storing intermediate results in temp tables may help if done right. I use this strategy as a last resort because temp tables are expensive and for large results sets they may be very expensive.

Answer (score 0):

I found this excelent article quite useful in answering this question:
[Paul White - temporary tables in stored procedures](http://web.archive.org/web/20180130201242/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2012/08/15/temporary-tables-in-stored-procedures.aspx)

Just to underline some concepts from the article:

- Temporary tables can be very useful as a way of simplifying a large query into smaller parts, giving the optimizer a better chance of finding good execution plans, providing statistical information about an intermediate result set
- Temporary objects may be cached across executions, despite explicit CREATE and DROP statements
- Statistics associated with a cached temporary object are also cached

On my behalf, I would just add that, if the stored procedure accesses the same data in another server more than once and we have a slow connection, it may be usefull to bring it into a temporary table. Of course, a table variable would also be valid for this purpose.